# Old google sheets buttons not workin

Tags: javascript, java, google-apps-script

About two years ago I created a sheet with some buttons with some code. I just recently wanted to work with it again, and all of the buttons are disabled, and I don't see the code I used for the buttons. How can I "reactivate" my code?

I know there was "script" there before, but when I click on the 3 dots, and "assign script" nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going into Extensions > Apps Script yet? In there you *should* see your custom script code. Once in there, you can check to ensure your code is all correct.

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the **Tools > Script editor** menu and verify that the function that you want to trigger is still in the code.
- Right-click on the button.
- Left-click on the three dots.
- Left-click on **Assign script**.
- Type the name of the function in the textbox.
- Click **OK**.

The next time you left-click the button, the function should run.  You may need to authorize the script, then run it.